# How to write a function that requires input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How can I create a function that requires input in JavaScript?

Example:

```
var a = 0;
var b;
function A(int myInteger){    //should it be something like var myInteger?
 // do something with myInteger
// print something or do a = myInteger;
}
function B(a){
// do something with recieved integer
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: There is no `int` keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Does what you have not work after you remove `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data types in JavaScript other than `var` everything is var in JS .

So when passing variable need not be mention the var also .just pass your value .same on creating function also .just mention the variable name. That's it .

so

```
var a = 0;
var b;
function A(a){    //passing your varible 
 // do something with a
// print something or do a = myInteger;
}
function B(b){
//Ex :call function A here 
A(b);
}
```

//Cheers .

As all said ..welcome to JS and W3School too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read some begginers tutorial for javascript.

To awnser the question:

```
var a = prompt('Input something here:');
/* do something here with a */
```

Then go to this site: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp and begin your learning journey.